#  Implementation of collide method in terms of ratio

Tags: python, list, sprite, pygame, collision

I would like to create a list of objects that collide with the user. However, I don't want to use the sprite.collide_rect_ratio() method because it creates a rectangular area that is too big for the collision (i.e. the objects seem to collide even though they are not really touching). I want to use the pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio(ratio): to fix the problem. How do I implement the method so that it returns a list of objects the user collides with?

It would implement the same code except with a smaller collision area as the following code:

```
sprite_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(myself, all_sprites_list, False)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of use to you,

What you may want to look into is "Per Pixel Collision", which will first use the bounding box of the object (what i suspect the `collide_rect` function does).

What you will need to do is find where the rectangles collide and how far within each other they are. You then check to see if there are any opaque pixels from one sprite touching any opaque pixels from the other sprite...

[This Link](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-per-pixel-collision) may be of use to you, its a very well done tutorial for a C++ framework similar to pygame.

The Per Pixel Collision code is half way down the page, and acts how I describe above.
Hopefully this is useful to you as it negates the need for the rectangle ratios due to 'invisible collisions'.

a quick google search may help you more with this type of collision detection.

For a bit of a boost heres some sample pygame code:

```
for s in sprites:
    # if no intersection then 'intersection' will be of size 0
    intersection = s.Rect.clip(user.rect)
    if intersection.width != 0 and intersection.height != 0:
        # perform collision detection
```

[Here is an already written and tested version](http://pygame.org/wiki/FastPixelPerfect) From the pygame wiki. Reading every thing on that page will give you a good knowledge on pixel collision and some good sample code which you can use straight away.

apologies if this was too far off topic but I feel this could be very useful to you as ratios (i feel) would not perform well for collision detection.

You may also want to look at [Rectangle documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) in pygame.

---

As for your question, looping through all sprites and using the `collide_rect_ratio` method would be the only way of using such a method to get a list of colliding sprites as far as i know.

Comment: how would you implement the "Per Pixel Collision" in pygame?

Comment: I Included a small bit of code in the answer which is how I would implement it. Using pygames `Rect.clip()` to get the intersection between the sprites bounding boxes I could make a preliminary collision detection (such as what you're doing, and from there I can just check each pixel in that intersection, I'll extend the `else` for you a bit though.